# Design patterns for translating dynamic content?

Tags: serialization, localization, internationalization

I want to store translations for user provided content.

I've seen some apps stores separate records for translations in each locale, but
I want to store all the translations in a record by serializing the translations, I mean

```
$post_title=serialize(['en_US'=>$enUS['title'], 'fr_FR'=>$frFR['title']]);
$post_content=serialize(['en_US'=>$enUS['conttent'], 'fr_FR'=>$frFR['conttent']);


$sql="INSERT INTO `posts` (`title`, `content`) VALUES(:post_title, :post_content)"
```

Is it a bad practice?

Comment: The reason behind storing separate records for translations in each locale is isolation. Which makes sense because you don't have to access French or Spanish when user has requested English. To be specific English of GB or English of US.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming (from your `INSERT` query) that you are using a relational DB, it can be considered a bad practice because:

- **Time and memory overhead**:To load a post in any language, you have to query for `$post_title` and `$post_content` which are the serialized data for all languages therefore your DB query results would have a larger memory footprint. Then you have to unserialize the fields to get to the content in your desired language and this also means additional cycles and unnecessary overhead if the front-end design does not need it; i.e. you are not showing the post in all available languages at the same time.
- **[Concurrency](http://erights.org/data/serial/jhu-paper/intro.html#concurrency)**: What if two translators update the translation of the same post into their respective languages *exactly at the same time*.
- **Breaking opacity**: As mentioned in one of the comments, another problem of serialization in this case is breaking the intended abstraction and encapsulation provided by your DB interface. This might not be a big concern when dealing with localization data, but if your DBMS offers you column-level privileges, then serializing everything in one column prevents you from using that feature.
- **Inconsistency in data modeling**: By using serialization in such a case, the conceptual data model (website with *post content* in multiple languages) ends up being incoherent with the logical data model (`$post_content` being something other than *post content* in a desired language). Simply put by looking at the data model, one can not say that these tables are used by a multilingual website.
- **i18n issues**: Mixing various languages as a serialized value in one column limits the possibility of using multiple encodings for your content; e.g. keeping Japanese in Shift-JIS, German in Latin1, and everything else in UTF8. Also, it makes checking for mojibake or other encoding issues harder without unserializing the data.

It can be considered a good workaround if:

- **Showing all languages together**: ...you never show the translations separately and they always appear or edited together.
- **Keep legacy data model**: ...you want to keep the data a legacy model intact. One does not have to change the existing data model to make way for multilingual content. This is helpful for internationalizing a legacy software without messing too much with the data model and dealing with DB migration.